# Does the Kafka Streams StreamBuilder always detect "duplicate" input topics?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

This code creates two `KStream` instances *separately*, both are reading from the *same* topic:

```
    final KStream<String, String> inputStream1 =
      builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC, consumed);
    final KStream<String, String> inputStream2 =
      builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC, consumed);

    final KStream<String, String> mappedStream1 = inputStream1
            .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("1: " + k + " -> " + v))
            .mapValues((ValueMapper<String, String>) String::toLowerCase);

    final KStream<String, String> mappedStream2 = inputStream2
            .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("2: " + k + " -> " + v))
            .mapValues((ValueMapper<String, String>) String::toUpperCase);

    mappedStream1.to(OUTPUT_TOPIC_1, produced);
    mappedStream2.to(OUTPUT_TOPIC_2, produced);
```

The topology looks like this: There is only one *source* definition which is then used *two times*:

```
Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [input])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000002, KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000004
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000002 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000003
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000004 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000005
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000003 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000006
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000002
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000005 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000007
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000004
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000006 (topic: output-1)
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000003
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000007 (topic: output-2)
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000005
```

Now my question is: Is it always safe to assume that the `StreamBuilder` creates only one source (= only one consumer for the same topic)?

In other words: Is it always guaranteed that - given a topic with multiple partitions - `inputStream1` and `inputStream2` see the same records?

Or is it better to rewrite it to something like this, to make it explicit:

```
    final KStream<String, String> inputStream =
      builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC, consumed);

    final KStream<String, String> mappedStream1 = inputStream
            .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("1: " + k + " -> " + v))
            .mapValues((ValueMapper<String, String>) String::toLowerCase);

    final KStream<String, String> mappedStream2 = inputStream
            .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("2: " + k + " -> " + v))
            .mapValues((ValueMapper<String, String>) String::toUpperCase);
```

**Update**

The 2nd version results in this topology:

```
Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [input])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000001, KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000003
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000001 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000002
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000003 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000004
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000002 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000005
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000001
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000004 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000006
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000003
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000005 (topic: output-1)
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000002
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000006 (topic: output-2)
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000004
```

Comment: Well, are the topologies the same?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have added the 2nd topology. The numbering is different, but structurally it seems to be equal.

Comment: Where do you define `builder`? Is the `application.id` the same for both configs? If so, then yeah, there's only one consumer instance per input partition that can run for either stream, as per limitations of the underlying consumer api

Comment: @OneCricketeer The `builder` would be the same, same `application.id`. You could post your comment as an answer, maybe including a reference where your statement is base on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `builder` would be the same, same `application.id`

Can't speak for the topology, but thinking about the flow at the Consumer API level, the `group.id` is built based on the `application.id`, therefore your consumer group would be the same for both streams.

With one input topic, only one consumer instance (between the two) would be able to consume from that input topic.

This would explain why there is only one source; therefore, you don't need additional `builder.stream()` calls with the same parameters.